# Blinking of an element with `:hover` CSS rule after file dropping on it

Tags: css

I have a file drop area that has `background-color: red`. This area changes its `background-color` to `gray` on `:hover` and when it has `drop-over` class, that I add on `dragenter` event and remove on `drop` event.

When I drop a file I see red blinking of this area (`.drop-over` is removed, but `:hover` CSS rule is not applied yet).

How to fix it with CSS?

```js
label.addEventListener("drop", event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    label.classList.remove("drop-over");
    console.log(event.dataTransfer.files);
});

label.addEventListener("dragenter", event => {
    label.classList.add("drop-over");
});

label.addEventListener("dragleave", event => {
    label.classList.remove("drop-over");
});

label.addEventListener("dragover", event => {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
#file-input {
    display: none;
}

label {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

label:hover, label.drop-over {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <input id="file-input" type="file">
    <label id="label" for="file-input">
    Drop Here
</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add it as a runnable code snippet??

Comment: I have tried on jsbin.com, but it does not work in iframe (I can't drop a file). I present the full code here, just create html file and put the code in it, run it by double click, no need a server.

Comment: Done, here it works

Comment: The blinking takes ~1 FPS, but it is notable.

Answer (score 0):

The question was how to fix it with CSS, and I still do not know how.

But if you need any decision, it possible to do with JS.

Replace inside the `drop` listener:

```js
label.classList.remove("drop-over");
```

with:

```js
setTimeout(_ => label.classList.remove("drop-over"), 50);
```